# feedback on my solution (integration)

Tags: calculus, integration

I need help in this problem. I managed to find the answer for this problem by using mathmatica but cannot do the working for it. i have done most of it but i am stuck on the last part.

[image: first page]

[image: second page]
[image]

Comment: integration problem need correct answer please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the standard differentiation rules you should be familiar with

$$\int\frac1{1+x^2}dx=\arctan x+C\;.$$

To handle

$$\int\frac{2x}{2+2x+x^2}dx\;,$$

notice that $2+2x+x^2=1+(x+1)^2$ and make the substitution $u=x+1$, $du=dx$, to get

$$\int\frac{2(u-1)}{1+u^2}du=\int\frac{2u}{1+u^2}du-2\int\frac1{1+u^2}du\;,$$

in which both integrals are straightforward.

Comment: so is the output from mathmatica correct?

Comment: @johnnitro: Yes.

Comment: "thanks" for help "+1"

Comment: @johnnitro: You’re welcome.